# Regex for string ending with particular pattern

Tags: python, regex

Hel lo, I just need the command in regex to ask to find any string that end with a . and any number

for instance

```
ASGSGSGGS.2
AHHAHAHAH.4
DJDDKGDGD.4
```

thank you for your help

I tried :

```
re.match(r".\.[0-9]",i)
```

Comment: Just do: `re.match("\.\d$")`

Comment: `res.match(r".*(\.\d*)$")` may work.

Comment: @Grendel can the string be `ASGSGSGGS.24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `$` anchor to match the end of the string:

```
re.search(r"\.[0-9]$", i)
```

Also, note that I'm using `re.search` instead of `re.match`. You can read about the differences between both functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: @sourcream See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: Idk what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [a-zA-Z]*\.[0-9]+$
```

You can try this.`match` always matches from start of string.
See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bSulCv/1

Comment: Downvoted since you added needless complexity to the pattern without any justifiable reason.